# Which adjective should I use to describe a phenomenon, that I hope will not appear in my experiment?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm writing a report for my electronic experiments. In the paper, I limit the frequency of the voltage resource to a small value because a high frequency reduces the impedance and causes large currency which is harmful to the equipment. My sentence is like this: "f should be lower than a defined upper limit to avoid over-current due to a (?) small impedance." I want to use an adjective to describe the "small impedance". It certainly appears but I don't wish it to appear for it causes damage.

Comment: Sorry to point this out and the Question is not about English; it's about electrics or electronics which often do use general English terms and here, you're looking for something specific to your course work; not relevant to general English.

Why are you not asking your tutor, or a senior student?

Comment: Try *undesirable.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's the smallness of the impedance, not the impedance, that might cause the trouble. You need to modify 'small', which requires an *ly*-word not an adjective.

*Excessively* works but sounds odd next to 'small'.

*Unacceptably* doesn't really highlight the knock-on effect, the risk.

*Dangerously* is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

In AC, impedance is always there.  You want to **limit** impedance to an acceptable value.

Answer (score -1):

[undesirable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undesirable):

> not desirable : unwanted